# Can you change the style of an object based on a property within the object in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface

I have a class for message, and the objects are being displayed in a ListBox and there's a property for the message based on whether it's sent to or from the user.  Is there a way to create two different styles and change them depending on this property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a DataTemplate for the type of the item you're displaying.  In that DataTemplate, you use a DataTrigger to control how the item varies in appearance depending upon a property of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. use dynamic resource
[link text](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/davids/archive/2009/05/19/staticresource-and-dynamicresource.aspx)